# How to reduce lag to render math on html?

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

So, I need to implement mathjax in a web project, Did some research on who is already using it and found that,

https://math.stackexchange.com/ Uses mathjax to render mathematical equations and formulas. But when it gets rendered on the browser it is slow and a lag is present. How could this be removed or reduced more then what is happening right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax is a very good renderer but isn't always the fastest. An alternative javascript math rendering library is [jqmath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html) That is noticably smaller and quicker than MathJax, but doesn't aim for all the same spacing refinements and the same coverage of latex math input.

The fastest rendering of course is just to use MathML in the page and require a browser that supports it. Current versions of Opera, Safari, Firefox and Chrome all support that to some extent. (For IE people need the free (not open source) MathPlayer plugin). My own [html5mathml](https://code.google.com/p/html5mathml/) JavaScript sometimes helps to smooth the gaps between the different browser implementations.

Comment: I tried Mathjax but there a lengthy html file that I pass through mathjax library. Does it make a difference to have large html file with more mathjax to load in more time. Obviously I know more content would need more time to render but is there anything like internal caching so that once a symbol appears it doesn't require rendering engine to translate it into math again ?

Comment: MJ renders/spaces entire expressions so I don't think individual symbols appearing in more than one expression saves much, it does do a lot of work to avoid re-rendering stuff on update or page reflow, but people with a lot more information about its internals than I have follow the mathjax tag so I'll let others comment on that. You can also configure how many expressions it does at a time so you can render the first few quickly and have the later ones being rendered while you look at the top of the page.